# why asp.net MVC called light weight?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

I heard that asp.net MVC is called light weight. And asp.net webforms are not that. But I could not get what it means by "light weight"?

Does that mean that asp.net MVC web pages loads quickly compare to that of asp.net webforms?

Comment: As far as I understand. Yes thats true because ASP.NET Web Forms architecture  RAD (RAPID APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT),  MVC isn't RAD because RAPID APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT approach fast  but complex. MVC is not complex.                                                                      I suggest you Simple web application + tight schedule = ASP.NET webforms.

Complex web application + tight schedule = ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @rootturk this is not correct. please review ur answer and see if it makes senese

Comment: asp.net mvc doesn't have any concept of view state. This is one of the reason why mvc called light weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the MVC framework itself is not that big.  This means that your code will have more control over the behaviour of the application however it may mean that you need to write more code in certain situations.

Webforms will provide more functionality for you but the downside is that you have less control and it also tends to produce bloated pages which take longer to load.   Because most of the code is generated automatically it tends to have a lot of stuff that may be unnecessary. There are lots of things happening "under the hood" which are not visible to the programmer.

MVC is also [open source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) so you could theoretically step through the code and see it working (even if you don't want to look at the source code someone else may do it for you on stackoverflow.com).

**For Example:**

The webforms gridview can display multiple rows and give you paging with only a few lines of code however if it stops working you won't know why.  You will probably use a trial and error approach, trying different things until it starts working again.  If you wanted similar functionality in MVC you would probably create a HTML table and use a [paging tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) from the MVC website. This would take longer but you could style it more easily and you can step through the code to debug it.

Comment: this is good info to share. but would be better if u add some examples

Comment: I have added an example but not included code snippets.